# Simpler way to repeat an execution with 2D points?

Tags: list-manipulation

q has the coordinates of quadrilateral. I can get the output below with brute-force but I want to find a simpler solution, perhaps something like `f<-q[[1;;2]]`.

**Initializations**

```
f[x_, y_] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}.{x, y} + {5, 6};
q = {{1, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}}
```

**Want: better way for this, perhaps in some matrix form?**

```
f[1, 1]
f[3, 1]
f[3, 2]
f[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f[{x_, y_}] := {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}.{x, y} + {5, 6};
q = {{1, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}}
f /@ q
(*
 {{8, 13}, {10, 19}, {12, 23}, {10, 17}}
*)
```

**Edit**
To understand the differences between `Map` and `Apply`, try the following (after running the code above):

```
ClearAll[g];
g @@@ q
(* {g[1, 1], g[3, 1], g[3, 2], g[1, 2]} *)

g /@ q
(* {g[{1, 1}], g[{3, 1}], g[{3, 2}], g[{1, 2}]} *)
```

**Edit**

BTW, you could also try:

```
g @ q
(* g[{{1, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}}] *)

g @@ q
(* g[{1, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}] *)
```

Note that each one of `@` , `@@` and `@@@` makes the function to be applied one level deeper on `q`.

Comment: Is this also a Apply -shorthand?

Comment: @hhh No, it's `Map`. Just put your cursor on the characters `/@` and press F1 (on Windows). Please note that Verde modified your function `f` subtly to make this work.

Answer (score 5):

I'd define `f` with [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html) (i.e. `:=`) rather than with [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html?q=Set&lang=en) (i.e. `=`), (see e.g. this tutorial [Immediate and Delayed Definitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html)) :

```
f[x_, y_] := {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}.{x, y} + {5, 6}
```

### `Apply`

Nevertheless if you modify your function `f` or if you don't, 
you will need [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html?q=Apply&lang=en) on the first level i.e `Apply[f, q, {1}]` or its shorthand :

```
f @@@ q
```

> ```
> {{8, 13}, {10, 19}, {12, 23}, {10, 17}}
> ```

"...perhaps in some matrix form..." - points collected in `q` represent a matrix, i.e.

```
MatrixQ @ q
```

> ```
> True
> ```

and `Apply` (`@@@`) is especially useful for matrices.

**Edit**

More verbose ways which could be helpful in more general cases than coordinates of quadrilaterals :

### `ReplaceAll`

[`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (i.e. `/.`) :

```
q /. {a_, b_} -> f[a, b]
```

and for a more complete answer some other ways :

### `Thread`

```
Thread[ f[ q[[All, 1]], q[[All, 2]] ] ]
```

### `MapThread`

```
MapThread[ f, Transpose @ q ]
```

### `Inner`

```
Inner[ f, q[[All, 1]], q[[All, 2]], List]
```